# Kerberos Ticket is Not Renewed

Tags: sql-server, jboss, kerberos, keytab

I am connecting to MSSQL Server via a datasource configured in JBoss EAP 6.4 with a security domain using the KerberosLoginModule.

My application connects successfully and works fine up to 10 hours. Afterwards, the Kerberos ticket expires, as 10 hours is the default lifetime for Active Directory as KDC, and my application fails with a "Ticket Expired (32)" error.

I don't understand why after the ticket expiration, the application is not trying to use the keytab again to obtain a new ticket.

Any clue?

Comment: Do you know the SPN for your MSSQL server data source?

Comment: Yes, but the SPN doesn't seem to be the problem. Actually the problem was the Kerberos ticket not being removed from the cache once expired. I will post my solution.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to solve my incident thanks to [this Red Hat support article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3153891).

What I was missing was the Infinispan's cache container for the datasource with a lifespan shorter than 10 hours, which is the default Kerberos ticket expiration lifespan. By setting a lower lifespan for the connection object in the cache, the ticket is evicted before expiring, and a new one is created with a later expiration date.